# how do I move specific files from one directory to other using xargs?

Tags: unix, xargs, mv

suppose I type this command:

```
find /etc/info/ -name ".c" | xargs -I {} grep -l 'importantFile' {}
```

Now I have all the files that I am interested, which has the suffix of .c and keywords "importantFile". How do I move it to one of my current directory(name: folder)?

I tried:

```
find /etc/info/ -name ".c" | xargs -I {} grep -l 'importantFile' {} mv{} ./folder
```

and it doesn't work. Please help :p

Comment: You need a wildcard for the `-name` option like: find /etc/info/ -name "*.c"

Answer (score 2):

If you like to stick with find, something like this should work:

```
xargs -r0 --arg-file <(find . -name "*.c" -type f -exec grep -lZ importantFile {} +
  ) mv -i --target-directory ./folder
```

Try this

```
grep -lir 'importantFile' /etc/info/*.c | xargs mv -t ./folder
```

Comment: what if I have to stick with find?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me moving copying some PDF

```
find . -name "*.pdf" | xargs -I % cp % ../testTarget/
```

So for your example it should be

```
 find /etc/info/ -name "*.c" | xargs -I % mv % ./folder
```

Comment: How to append date to moved file filename