# How to I search for a text string and copy those files to another directory

Tags: unix, command-line, find, xargs, cp

I need to find a text string within some files. This will give me a list:

`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -il "google"`

then I need to copy those files to a folder and rename them. So I think I need to pipe them again to something like this

```
| xargs -0 -n1  -I '{}' cp '{}' ../testTarget/{}_RECOVERED
```

Alas:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -il "google" |
xargs -0 -n1  -I '{}' cp '{}' ../testTarget/{}_RECOVERED
```

Results: `cp: {}: No such file or directory`

Please advise

- the filenames have space and commas in them (Dovecot)

Comment: link to a solution to a similar question


http://stackoverflow.com/a/17392643/975114

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -lh "google" | xargs -I % cp % ../testTarget/%_RECOVERED
```

or

```
find SOURCE/ -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -lh "SEARCH_STRING" | xargs -I % cp % TARGET_DIR/%_RECOVERED
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in `ls -1tr`
{
SEARCH_STRING_LINE_NO=`grep -n SEARCH_STRING i | cut -d: -f1`;
if [ SEARCH_STRING_LINE_NO > 0 ] then
cp i folder_path_where_u_want_to_copy
fi
}
```

Replace SEARCH_STRING with the text string you want to find.

Replace folder_path_where_u_want_to_copy with the folder path where u want to move the files containing SEARCH_STRING

This should copy the files containing SEARCH_STRING to the folder folder_path_where_u_want_to_copy

I have not tested this code as I dont have a unix box with me right now, but atleast it should give u an idea to approach

Comment: The problems seem to be that this does not handle spaces in the file names. This is how I adjusted the script. 'code'
#! /bin/bash

for i in `ls -1tr`
 do
  SEARCH_STRING_LINE_NO=`grep -n "google" $i | cut -d: -f1`;
  if [ SEARCH_STRING_LINE_NO > 0 ]
    then
     cp $i "testTarget/"
  fi
 done

Answer (score 0):

The following command will `grep` for `pattern` and `copy` the files to your desired location.

```
find /path/to/search -type f -exec grep -q "pattern" '{}' ';' -exec cp '{}' /path/to/copy ';'
```

Once the files are copied over you can use `rename` command to rename them accordingly.